# In Swift getting error Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

Required extension for Dictionary as to get text key value if exist.

Implemented below code and it is successfully compiled:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: AnyObject {
    func getValueForKeyPath(keyValue: String) -> String {
        return ((self["item_qty"] as? Dictionary<String, String>) ?? ["": ""])?["text"] ?? ""
    }
}
```

But when I did small change in method getting error as:

> "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' "

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: AnyObject {
    func getValueForKeyPath(keyValue: String) -> String {
        return ((self[keyValue] as? Dictionary<String, String>) ?? ["": ""])?["text"] ?? ""
    }
}
```

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to cast `keyValue` to *Key*. For example:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: AnyObject {
    func getValueForKeyPath(keyValue : String) -> String{
        return ((self[keyValue as! Key] as? Dictionary<String,String>) ?? ["":""])?["text"] ?? ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by @Hoa compiles, it'll crash under certain circumstances (i.e. when `Dictionary.Key` is not a `String`).

A better solution might be to use one of the `init(...)` methods from the `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` protocol.

*Notice the extra generic constraint:* `Key.StringLiteralType == String`. This allows us to use `keyValue` to instantiate a `Key` object and then use **that** in `self[key]`.
*I think we can assume pretty much all strings used are `String`, so this shouldn't affect anything.*

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral,
  Key.StringLiteralType == String,
  Value: AnyObject {

  func getValueForKeyPath(keyValue: String) -> String {
    let key = Key(stringLiteral: keyValue) // <-- this is key

    return ((self[key] as? Dictionary<String, String>) ?? ["": ""])?["text"] ?? ""
  }
}
```

---

As a side note, it might be worth making that return statement a little clearer and easier to debug:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral,
  Key.StringLiteralType == String,
  Value: AnyObject {

  func getValueForKeyPath(keyValue: String) -> String {
    let key = Key(stringLiteral: keyValue)

    guard let dict = self[key] as? Dictionary<String, String>,
      let text = dict["text"]
      else {
        return ""
    }

    return text
  }
}
```